# Attempting to get susy grid to work with bones theme

Tags: sass, config, susy-compass

**I have the following configuration file**

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require 'susy'
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "library/css"
sass_dir = "library/scss"
images_dir = "library/images"
javascripts_dir = "library/js"
fonts_dir = "library/fonts"

output_style = :nested
```

**I also have the following scss file which is being watched by compass**(I have a container surrounding my content so I should see the grid, but i dont see it, so susy is obviously not working, but I am not sure why? any help would be greatly appreciated)

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Imports

@import "susy";

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Basic Grid

$total-columns  : 12;
$column-width   : 4em;
$gutter-width   : 1em;
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width;

$show-grid-backgrounds  : true;




/*
.onecol    { width: 5.801104972%;  }       
.twocol    { width: 14.364640883%; }       
.threecol  { width: 22.928176794%; }       
.fourcol   { width: 31.491712705%; }       
.fivecol   { width: 40.055248616%; }      
.sixcol    { width: 48.618784527%; }      
.sevencol  { width: 57.182320438000005%; } 
.eightcol  { width: 65.74585634900001%; } 
.ninecol   { width: 74.30939226%; }        
.tencol    { width: 82.87292817100001%; }  
.elevencol { width: 91.436464082%; }       
.twelvecol { width: 99.999999993%; }      
*/

// layout & column defaults
.onecol, .twocol, .threecol, .fourcol, .fivecol, .sixcol, .sevencol, .eightcol, .ninecol, .tencol, .elevencol, .twelvecol {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2.762430939%;
}

.first {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.last {
  float: right;
}

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Layout */

.container {
  @include container;
  @include susy-grid-background;
}
```

Comment: Hey I'm also looking to add susy grid to my bones theme. Where did you add the above code? Did you just add it to the top of the _base partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oops turns out I had a id of container instead of a class of container in my html. Sorry.

Comment: I do this kind of stuff ALL the time - welcome to the party ;D